# Nuxt2 - watch route change

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I know this was asked a couple of times, but I do not understand something about watching for a route change in Nuxt2.

It doesn't work for me.

My code is:

```js
watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      console.log('route change to', to)
      console.log('route change from', from)
    },
  },
```

**Minimal reproducable example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-feather-90gbjm

**Expected behavior**

show console logs on route change.

**result**

nothing happens

Comment: Probably because you watch it only in a specific page, hence when you're coming or leaving it, it's not watching it the first time. (maybe `immediate: true` could help here) Still, it's probably better to have this kind of watcher in a middleware or in a wrapping layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could solve this by adding the watcher on the `layout` that the index and about pages are rendered.

```
| pages
  | index.vue
  | about.vue
| layouts
  | base.vue
```

In `layouts/base.vue`

```html
<template>
  <Nuxt />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ....
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      console.log('route change to', to)
      console.log('route change from', from)
    },
  },
  ....
}
</script>
```

In `index.vue` and `about.vue`

```html
<template>
  ... Many things here
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'base',
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Or use the `/layouts/default.vue`, that way you don't even need to specify it.

Comment: Nice, this worked. I was trying to setup the watcher in a component. It makes sense if you think about it, because routes only work for the whole page and not a component itself.

Answer (score 3):

With **Nuxt 3**, you can use `onBeforeRouteUpdate` from `vue-router`:

```
<script setup>
import { onBeforeRouteUpdate } from "vue-router"

onBeforeRouteUpdate((newRoute) => {
    console.log(newRoute)
})
</script>
```