# In Nuxt/VueJs, how can I get SendInBlue Chat Widget to see route changes?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, sendinblue

I'm using SendInBlue chat widget on a Nuxt/VueJs website. Through the
[SendInBlue Conversations UI](https://conversations-app.sendinblue.com/visitors),
the widget reports the visitor's page current location (url and title).
However, the location does not change when the internal route changes (no hard browser location change).
I want to see the location changes.

How can I notify the SendInBlue Chat Widget that the route is changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The
[SendInBlue Chat Widget API](https://developers.sendinblue.com/docs/javascript-api-reference#pageview)
includes a pageView method that can be called to alert the widget to a route change.

```js
SibConversations('pageView')
```

[This Answer about watching a route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71685443/10118631)
provides the basic framework. Note that in my case I added the code to the `/layouts/default.vue` since it renders most of my pages. (Add to all necessary layouts.)

```html
<script>
export default {
  watch: {
    $route() {
      // on route change, notify SendInBlue Chat Widget so it updates visitor location
      if (process.client) {
        // delay 0.5 seconds to be sure route has actually changed ($nexttick does show correct page title)
        window.setTimeout(() => {
          window.SibConversations('pageView')
        }, 500)
      }
    },
  },
  // ... and data, methods, etc., as needed
}
</script>
```

So now when the route changes, we notify the widget.

Note: If we trigger `window.SibConversations('pageView')` without a delay, I found that the title is not correct. I'm assuming the page is not yet rendered. I tried using `this.$nexttick`, but the title is still not present. So, I use window.setTimeout() to provide a short delay. I found that 100ms works for me, but I used a longer time in case a slower computer took longer. (And we aren't worried about half-second accuracy.)

I also wrapped the call to ensure it's only called on client side. No nasty "windows undefined" errors.