# Nuxt 3 cache and pagination with useNuxtData

Tags: caching, pagination, nuxt3, usefetch

Since latest Nuxt 3 version, cache has to be manually handled using `useNuxtData()` composable.

This code is an extract of what I do to cache a single detail post, calling an API endpoint.

```js
const post = ref({})
// Get cached post using slug as cache key 
const cachedPost = useNuxtData(route.params.slug)

// If post is cached, use it, otherwise fetch it
if (cachedPost.data.value) {
  post.value = cachedPost.data.value
} else {
  const { data, error } = await useFetch(`/public/posts/${route.params.slug}`, {
      key: route.params.slug
  })

  post.value = data.value
}
```

Now I want to show a list of category posts using cursor pagination, so I'm doing this

```js
const categoryData = ref({})
const cachedCategoryData = useNuxtData(`${route.params.category}${lastId.value ? '-'+lastId.value : ''}`)
const lastId = computed(() => route.query.lastid)

// If category is cached, use it, otherwise fetch it
if (cachedCategoryData.data.value) {
  categoryData.value = cachedCategoryData.data.value
} else {
  const { data, error } = await useFetch(`/public/category/${route.params.category}`,
  {
    key: `${route.params.category}${lastId.value ? '-'+lastId.value : ''}`,
    watch: [lastId],
    query: { lastid: lastId }
  })

  categoryData.value = data.value
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that despite watcher works and it fetches the data again when `lastId` changes, results are not being propagated to `categoryData`.

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I see from your code:

```js
const cachedCategoryData = useNuxtData(`${route.params.category}${lastId.value ? '-'+lastId.value : ''}`)
const lastId = computed(() => route.query.lastid)
```

In JavaScript, order matters. Variables should be declared before they are used. Your `lastId` is computed based on the route query, which is declared after it is used in `cachedCategoryData`. That is a potential source of the issue you are seeing.

```js
const lastId = computed(() => route.query.lastid)
const cacheKey = computed(() => `${route.params.category}${lastId.value ? '-'+lastId.value : ''}`)
const cachedCategoryData = useNuxtData(cacheKey.value)
```

And, still from your code:

```js
const { data, error } = await useFetch(`/public/category/${route.params.category}`, {
  key: `${route.params.category}${lastId.value ? '-'+lastId.value : ''}`,
  watch: [lastId],
  query: { lastid: lastId }
})
```

Plus, [Nuxt (v3)](https://nuxt.com/) automatically watches for route changes, including changes in query parameters. So, If `lastId` is a route query parameter, you do not need to watch it in your `useFetch` call

```js
const { data, error } = await useFetch(`/public/category/${route.params.category}`, {
  key: cacheKey.value,
  query: { lastid: lastId.value }
})
```

Also, make sure to handle potential errors during fetch calls. That way, you can determine whether the issue is due to a failed API call or some other issue in your code. Here, make sure your API endpoint `/public/category/${route.params.category}` responds with the correct data and HTTP status code.

Revised code addition:

```js
if (error.value) {
  console.error(`Error fetching data: ${error.value}`)
  // Handle error appropriately
  return
}
```

Finally, check if you are updating the route query `lastid` correctly as you paginate. If it is not updated correctly, `lastId` computed property will not change and hence the watcher will not trigger `useFetch`.

Here is the revised code, taking into account those remarks:

```js
const categoryData = ref({})
const lastId = computed(() => route.query.lastid)
const cacheKey = computed(() => `${route.params.category}${lastId.value ? '-'+lastId.value : ''}`)

const cachedCategoryData = useNuxtData(cacheKey.value)

// If category is cached, use it, otherwise fetch it
if (cachedCategoryData.data.value) {
  categoryData.value = cachedCategoryData.data.value
} else {
  const { data, error } = await useFetch(`/public/category/${route.params.category}`, {
    key: cacheKey.value,
    query: { lastid: lastId.value }
  })

  if (error.value) {
    console.error(`Error fetching data: ${error.value}`)
    // Handle error appropriately
    return
  }

  categoryData.value = data.value
}
```

If the issue still persists, consider debugging each step of your application's flow to find where the data is not being updated as expected.

---

As noted in "[Nuxt2 - watch route change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75832328/6309)", With Nuxt 3, you can use [`onBeforeRouteUpdate`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/on-before-route-update) from `vue-router`.

The `onBeforeRouteUpdate` method is a Vue Router lifecycle hook, and it allows you to execute some logic before the current route changes, but while the component instance is being reused (e.g., when route parameters change).

In your case, the main issues in your original code were related to the order of declarations and the unnecessary watching of `lastId` in `useFetch`.
Since you are using the [`useFetch` method](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch) provided by Nuxt, which already includes reactive features and should trigger a fetch whenever a watched reactive source changes, `onBeforeRouteUpdate` may not be necessary.